# Using JavaScript to our advantage?

Tags: javascript

I just recently started learning JavaScript and a question came up, but I couldn't find an exact answer for it. So, please bear with me, if I say something foolish, or I make connection between unrelated things.

There's a simple example: when going to the videos page of a Youtube channel, a script (possibly) loads 30 videos on the page, like "page 1". When scrolling reaches the bottom, it loads another 30 videos.

#1 So the question is: can I run JavaScript code in the browser's console for example, to *force* this "event" and could I do it with custom arguments to make it load 35 instead of 30? Or this is something which is server sided and cannot be modified?

#2 To extend this question, if it is possible, is it because we have access to the "API"? If no credentials are needed to actually list those videos on the site, then we can just "command" it to load or to load more in my example? Or even make this change applied automatically with something like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For more clarity: Are you asking if you can create a script that modifies the functionality of youtube.com or are you using youtube as an example?

Comment: Sometimes it becomes very difficult to determine how to "force" the event, and often times no, you cannot specify "custom" arguments because the server does not support them.

Comment: Usually webpages like YouTube enclose their variables in modules for safety. So you most likely can't directly trigger the event. What can be done is emulate the event on the element with the listener to make the YouTube script think that the page has been scrolled.

Comment: Answer to 1st question - Yes, Answer to 2nd Question - No, since its a DOM event which actually loads these 30 more videos, you have access to all DOM events from the browser. you can simply do something like `window.scrollTo(x,y)` in your browser console to try and trigger this event. This is possible only because we are mimicking general user behaviour just by JS. I just tried this on youtube and it works probably should work anywhere where something similar is done :)

Comment: Youtube.com was just an example, this actually occurred to me with another site. But this is what I wanted to know, if access can be locked partially or entirely to these events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you manage to manipulate the JS you'll still be limited by what their API allows. The scroll -> load behaviour on YouTube channels uses the `https://www.youtube.com/browse_ajax?` API endpoint and passes a "continuation token", so instead of saying "give me page 10" or "give me 20 results starting with the 80th" you say "give me the first page" and then that response contains a "continuation token" that when sent will give you the "next page". This means you can't control the number of loaded results through the API call. It's configured server-side, you have no control over it. The only thing you could maybe do is load *multiple pages* instead of just one.

Comment: Is this true for all sites that use a similar "load more" method with videos or pictures for example, or there are sites (not for such a big company as Google) which solves this with JS only and make this possible?

Comment: You'll find a lot of different implementations of pagination. Some will allow you to send "how many per page" but the actual values are limited to a list (so 10, 20, 40, 60, not any number). Some will ask for a page index. some will ask for size + offset. Some will send you complete URLs for requesting the next page. Why different implementations? Because everyone has different needs. Youtube for example might have gone this way because it's easier to cache results if the API is more strict in what it expects as input.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!